# Where can I find the proof of this Ramanujan result?

Tags: reference-request

I'm searching for a proof of one impressive Ramanujan result. Not one in particular, the only request I have is to be really impressive.
For example
$$
\sqrt{\phi+2}-\phi=\frac{e^{-2\pi/5}}{1+\frac{e^{-2\pi}}{1+\frac{e^{-4\pi}}{1+\cdots}}}
$$
where $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$.

Or maybe
$$
\frac1{\pi}=\frac{2\sqrt2}{9801}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(4n)!(1103+26390n)}{(n!)^4396^{4n}}\;.
$$

Can someone suggest me a precise reference where to find such a proof?

Thank you all

Comment: The first result is known as [Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers%E2%80%93Ramanujan_continued_fraction). In the reference section of the wiki page, there is a [survey article](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~berndt/articles/rrcf.pdf) of this stuff by Berndt, B, et al.

Comment: Both the results you have mentioned are very famous. First one is proved in one of my blog posts http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/09/values-of-rogers-ramanujan-continued-fraction-part-1.html and I have given Ramanujan's theory of series for $1/\pi$ in posts starting from http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/03/modular-equations-and-approximations-to-pi-part-1.html

Answer (score 2):

The series for $1/\pi$ is proved in J. M. Borwein and P. B. Borwein, Pi and the AGM; A Study in Analytic Number Theory and Computational Complexity, Wiley, New York, 1987.

See also [Motivation for Ramanujan's mysterious $\pi$ formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14115/motivation-for-ramanujans-mysterious-pi-formula)