# Identities related to hypergeometric functions

Tags: calculus, special-functions

It is known that hypergeometric functions are closely related to the formula of $\pi$ given by [Ramanujan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14115/motivation-for-ramanujans-mysterious-pi-formula). Trying to master the proof given by the Borwein brothers, I got two identities:

$$\mathrm{A}:(1+k^2)\left(\frac{2K(k)}{\pi}\right)^2={}_3 F_2\left(\begin{matrix}1/4& 3/4& 1/2\\1& 1\end{matrix};\frac{16k^2(1-k^2)^2}{(1+k^2)^4}\right)$$

with $0\leq k\leq\sqrt{2}-1$ and

$$\mathrm{B}:(\frac{1+k^2}{2})\left(\frac{2K^{\prime}(k)}{\pi}\right)^2={}_3 F_2\left(\begin{matrix}1/4& 3/4& 1/2\\1& 1\end{matrix};\frac{16k^2(1-k^2)^2}{(1+k^2)^4}\right)$$

with $\sqrt{2}-1\leq k\leq\sqrt{2}+1$, where $K$ and $K^\prime=K(\sqrt{1-k^2})$ are [complete elliptic integrals of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), $F$ is [generalized hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function).

**Question:** Does A imply B(or B imply A)?

Comment: As written, these can't both be true. Since the RHS of each are the same, both being true amounts to $$(1+k^2)\left(\frac{2K(k)}{\pi}\right)^2=\frac{1+k^2}{2}\left(\frac{2K'(k)}{\pi}\right)^2$$
which simplifies to $K'(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}K(k)$. But this would mean that $K'(k)$ is an exponential function in $k$, which is false.

Comment: Eh, $K^{\prime}$ does not represent the derivative of $K$ in elliptic integral theory. It is $K(\sqrt{1-k^2})$

Comment: Ah. I'd remembered the $k'$ convention for the compl. modulus but forgotten that it also applied to $K'(k)$ as the compl. elliptic integral. Though, does that actually help? The complementary elliptic integral isn't proportional to the usual one. (The case of $k=1/\sqrt{2}\implies K(k)=K(k)/\sqrt{2}$ is a particularly evident counter-example.)

Comment: Hmm. A and B cannot be simultaneously true for the same k. I am wondering whether a transformation formula exists. RHS has a singular point at $\sqrt{2}-1$, and I need such a formula for analytic continuation, and I hope this would help.

Comment: Given that they both can't be true for all $k$, perhaps you should edit your question include the steps you used to obtain them? That would clarify the context and hopefully show where things went bad.

Comment: I use Clausen's formula and linear transformation formula for the deduction, and things might go bad for the hypergeometric functions are multi-valued around its singularities. A numerical computation on Mathematica suggest that A is true for $0<k<\sqrt{2}-1$ while B is true for $k>\sqrt{2}-1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18349/discussion-between-semiclassical-and-y-zhao).