# Generalizing Bellard's "exotic" formula for $\pi$ to $m=11$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, pi, computational-mathematics

Bellard's "exotic" pi formula has the form,

$$a\pi+b = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{P(n)}{{\displaystyle \binom{mn}{2n}2^{n-1}}}$$

where $a,b,m$ are integers and he uses $m=7$. However, it seems there are an infinite number of such formulas for other orders $m$.

> **I. Orders**

**Order 3:**

$$\pi+6 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{-6+50n}{{\displaystyle \tbinom{3n}{2n}2^{n}}}\tag1$$

$$3\pi+23 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{7+125n^2}{{\displaystyle \tbinom{3n}{2n}2^{n}}}$$

$$91\pi+831 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{129+3125n^3}{{\displaystyle \tbinom{3n}{2n}2^{n}}}$$

and so on. (*Edited*) Since $\binom{mn}{pn} = \binom{mn}{(m-p)n}$, then $(1)$ is equivalent to the form (by Gosper),

$$\pi = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{-6+50n}{{\displaystyle \tbinom{3n}{n}2^{n}}}.$$

**Order 7:**

$$740025\pi+20379280 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{3P_1(n)}{{\displaystyle \tbinom{7n}{2n}2^{n-1}}}\tag{2a}$$

$$740025\pi+19755520 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{P_2(n)}{{\displaystyle \tbinom{7n}{2n}2^{n-1}}}\tag{2b}$$

where,

$$\small{P_1(n) = 10996648 - 196882274 n + 1031962795 n^2 - 2942969225 n^3 + 3125347237 n^4 - 885673181 n^5}$$

$$\small{P_2(n) = 20202864 - 361815268 n + 1669902852 n^2 - 4185508285 n^3 + 1811392311 n^4 + 3820998353 n^5 - 2124144507 n^6.}$$

1. The eqn $(2a)$ is Bellard's, but I found there are also $P(n)$ that are $6$th, $7$th deg, and so on, with different $a,b$.
2. Note that $a=740025 = 3^2\cdot5^2\cdot11\cdot13\cdot23$ factors into small primes and which is a good "test" for the next orders.

**Order 11:** (by yours truly)

$$7997795704284513820875\pi+186851093786889785568000= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{P(n)}{{\displaystyle \tbinom{11n}{2n}2^{n-1}}}\tag3$$

where,

$$\small{P(n) = -1560353362660981617724800 + 50163087598613671757825520 n - 
  582276421453108529245554812 n^2 + 3934659571398075493770398672 n^3 - 
  14317202423564834332818033237 n^4 + 33962269581940193651909397387 n^5 - 
  43329011662268469435221715498 n^6 + 28124977321512890382308084178 n^7 - 
  4829379078844103835855196933 n^8 - 1529681997002493500502814877 n^9.}$$

1. There are also $P(n)$ that are $10$th, $11$th deg, and so on, with different $a,b$.
2. The prime factors of $a=7997795704284513820875$ are,
   $$3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 23, 37, 41, 43, 59, 61, 79.$$

> **II. Comment**

1. I found these using *Mathematica's* integer relations sub-routine. It **could not** find similar identities for order $m=4v+1=5,9,13$ with proportionately-sized coefficients, indicating that these may be only for $m = 4v+3 = 3,7,11,\dots$

> **III. Questions**

1. Can one find identities for *all* $m = 4v+3 = 3,7,11,\dots$?
2. Is there really an infinite number of identities per order $m$?

Comment: What exactly is the reason behind the existence of these expressions ? Are the polynomials in question unique for each *n* $($save multiplication by a constant, of course$)$ ?

Comment: @Lucian: You mean for each order $m$? Apparently the polynomials $P(n)$ are unique. The one for $m=3$ seems easiest to tackle since there are only four terms to track, so there might be a closed-form. I surprised Bellard didn't check $m=7$ if there were other $P(n)$ that would do, nor why he didn't check $m=11$. (Must be speed constraints since he found it back in 1997.)

Comment: Is Bellard's work published anywhere?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Only in Mathworld and Bellard's [website](http://bellard.org/pi/). I don't think it has been rigorously proven yet.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Ah, yes... $1997$... [those were the days](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086617) ! :-$)$

Comment: Have you seen Gourévitch, Boris; Guillera Goyanes, Jesús
Construction of binomial sums for $\pi$ and polylogarithmic constants inspired by BBP formulas, 
Appl. Math. E-Notes 7 (2007), 237–246?

Comment: Yes, yesterday. The paper [is here](http://www.math.nthu.edu.tw/~amen/2007/061028-2.pdf). However, they don't prove Gourevitch's formula there. I just noticed one of their formulas, $$\pi = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{-6+50n}{{\displaystyle \tbinom{3n}{n}2^{n}}}$$ is similar to the first one for $m=3$, $$\pi+6 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{-6+50n}{{\displaystyle \tbinom{3n}{2n}2^{n}}}$$

Comment: @Lucian: Since I used to live near HongKong, I just remember 1997 as the year the UK handed HK back to China.  :)

Comment: Glad to see such formulas pouring in. I wish the smaller and simpler formulas like $$\pi+6 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{-6+50n}{{\displaystyle \binom{3n}{2n}2^{n}}}$$ had any published proof.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I was familiar with Bellard's formula before, but thanks to your [recent question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1323465/), I decided to re-visit it and the $m=11$ was born. :) (Even if I checked it for only a finite number of decimal places, the fact that $a$ for $m=11, 15$ has that very highly-composite form is reassuring.)

Comment: I did check the paper (http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~kratt/artikel/pi.html) of Almkvist for proof of the formula $\pi + 6 = \cdots$ mentioned above. It seems that this scheme requires the integration of complicated rational functions and $\pi$ comes as a value of $\arctan$. It appears that this integration can be carried out by Symbolic packages for values of $m \leq 16$ so far. Thus the Bellard's formula for $m = 7$ is already proven.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I don't think they've proven Bellard's formula yet. They used $$\binom{mn}{pn}$$ where $m=8k$, $p=4k$, for any $k$. Perhaps they meant "for any integer $k$", hence **their $m$ is even**? (I can't open the file.)

Comment: Check page 3 of their paper where they give a table of values of $m$ and $p$ for which formulas have been found. Your formula for $m = 11$ does not appear in their list. Bellard's formula is second entry in the list. Next on Page 4 they mention that the integrals can be calculated for $m \leq 16$ via brute force using Maple.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Here's a pdf version at http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0110238. When they say, "...for $m\leq16$ the integrals can be computed by brute force using _Maple_", I believe they refer _only_ to the $m$ in their list of particular formulas they found.  Since for some reason they didn't find (or look for) $m=11$, then I don't think _Maple_ can prove the pi formula using $$\binom{11n}{2n}$$ Maybe Robert Israel can settle the matter since he is an expert with _Maple_. :)

Comment: If you don't get any answers here, you might consider writing to Jonathan Borwein. It looks like his kind of thing.