# Is there a series to show $22\pi^4>2143\,$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, approximation, pi

This extends [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1647360/4781).

> I. For $\pi^3$:

$$\pi^6-31^2 =\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\frac{63}{(2k+2)^6}+\frac{31^2}{(2k+3)^6}\right) =\sum_{k=0}^\infty P_1(k)\tag1$$

As pointed out by J. Lafont, when $P_1(k)$ is expanded out, its coefficients are all positive. Thus so is the $\text{LHS}$, implying $\pi^3>31$.

> II. For $\pi^4$:

The convergents of $\pi^4$ are,

$$97,\, \frac{195}{2},\, \frac{487}{5},\, \frac{1656}{17},\, \frac{2143}{22},\dots$$

The last one, being the particularly close approximation $22\pi^4 \approx 2143.0000027$, was mentioned by Ramanujan. (See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359015/).) Using,

$$\frac{\pi^8}{9450}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)^8}$$

$$\frac{17\pi^8}{161280}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)^8}$$

and the *same method* to find $(1)$, we get,

$$\pi^8-\Big(\frac{487}{5}\Big)^2 =\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{381}{5(2k+2)^8}+\frac{r_1^2}{(2k+3)^8}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P_2(k)\tag2$$

$$\pi^8-\Big(\frac{2143}{22}\Big)^2 =\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\frac{181695}{11^2(2k+2)^8}+\frac{r_2^2}{(2k+3)^8}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty Q_1(k)\tag3$$

$$\pi^8-\Big(\frac{2143}{22}\Big)^2 =\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{r_2^2}{(k+2)^8}-\frac{70208}{1815(2k+1)^8} \right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty Q_2(k)\tag4$$

where $r_1 =\frac{487}{5},\,$ $r_2 =\frac{2143}{22}$. The coefficients of $P_2(k)$ are all positive, so $5\pi^4>487$.

However, when the $Q_i(k)$ are expanded out, the constant term for both is ***negative***, so we cannot make an analogous conclusion. (In fact, it takes several terms before the sum turns positive.)

> **Q:** Can one find a ***similar*** series for $\pi^8-\Big(\frac{2143}{22}\Big)^2 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty R(k)$ such that ***all*** coefficients are positive and immediately implying $22\pi^4>2143$?

Comment: Like the phrase "extends this post" first time seen this, nice

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger:Oops, thanks.

Comment: If nothing comes out for $\pi^4-\frac{2143}{22}$ from$\pi^8$, how about $\pi^{12}$?

Comment: Another solution might come from adding a suitable zero relation, similarly to changing Gregory-Leibniz series for $\frac{\pi}{4}$ into Lehmer's for $\frac{\pi}{3}$, which proves $\pi>3$ with one term. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14113/series-that-converge-to-pi-quickly/1639961#1639961

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont: You're right, $\pi^{12}$ can be used to prove $\pi^4 >\frac{2143}{22}$. Thanks. :)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Is there a series for $\left(\frac{22}{7}\right)^k-\pi^k$ for some positive integer $k$? (simpler than the one by Adamchik and Wagon from Ferguson's)

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont: Can you give me a link to the one by Adamchik?

Comment: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/articles/pi/pi.pdf page 8 Have fun!

Comment: here I wrote it explicitly
https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Jaume_Oliver_Lafont/Constants#Series_involving_convergents_to_Pi

Comment: Here are two series for $\frac{22}{7}-\pi$
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652812/a-series-to-prove-frac227-pi0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to a clever [suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649890/is-there-a-series-to-show-22-pi42143#comment3367004_1649890) by J. Lafont, ***there is a series*** that can prove $\displaystyle\pi^4>\frac{2143}{22}$. However, it does not use $\pi^8$ but $\pi^{12}$. We start with,

$$\frac{691\pi^{12}}{638512875} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)^{12}}$$

$$\frac{691\pi^{12}}{638668800}-1 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+3)^{12}}$$

Multiply them with unknowns $a,b,$ then add the two,

$$\frac{691}{420}\frac{(4096a+4095b)\pi^{12}}{13!}-b = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{a}{(k+1)^{12}}+\frac{b}{(2k+3)^{12}}\right)$$

Let $b=\big(\frac{2143}{22}\big)^3$, and choose $a$ such that $\pi^{12}$ has a unit coefficient. We then get,

$$\begin{aligned}\pi^{12}-\Big(\frac{2143}{22}\Big)^3
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left( -\frac{52410418515}{691\cdot10648\cdot(2k+2)^{12}} +\Big(\frac{2143}{22}\Big)^3\frac{1}{(2k+3)^{12}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty R(k)
\end{aligned}$$

When expanded out, the coefficients of $R(k)$ are ***all positive***. Thus, the $\text{LHS}$ must be positive. Since it is a difference of two cubes $p^3-q^3 = (p-q)(p^2+pq+q^2)$, then that implies $\displaystyle\pi^4>\frac{2143}{22}.$

Comment: I revised the series for $\pi^6-961$, so now there is a version with positive coefficients that does not need any further expansion. Would you like to try that improved method on $\pi^{12}-\left(\frac{2143}{22}\right)^3$? Here it is: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1651175/134791

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont: I saw the edited version. Ah, quite nice.

Answer (score 3):

From the accelerated series
$$\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}=\frac{36}{17}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }
\frac{1}{n^{4}\dbinom{2n}{n}}$$
([Convergence acceleration technique for $\zeta(4)$ (or for $\eta(4)$) via creative telescoping?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281000/convergence-acceleration-technique-for-zeta4-or-for-eta4-via-creativ))

we have the direct sum

$$\pi^4 -\frac{2143}{22}= \frac{5}{52898832} \sum_{n=10}^\infty \left( \frac{1998926767}{n^4\dbinom{2n}{n}}+\frac{17452241}{(n+1)^4\dbinom{2(n+1)}{n+1}}\right)$$

The denominator in the coefficient fraction factors into small primes:
$$52898832=(2·3·7)^4·17$$

This series may be related to [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331167/generalizing-bellards-exotic-formula-for-pi-to-m-11).