# Convergence acceleration technique for $\zeta(4)$ (or $\eta(4)$) via creative telescoping?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, experimental-mathematics, convergence-acceleration

> **Question**
>
> 1. Is it already known whether the $\zeta(4):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^4$ accelerated convergence series $(1)$, proved for instance in [1, Corollaire 5.3], could be obtained by a similar technique to the ones explained by Alf van der Poorten in [2, section 1] for $\zeta(3)$ and $\zeta(2)$?
>      $$\zeta(4)=\frac{36}{17}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{4}\binom{2n}{n}}.\tag{1}$$
> 2. (a) In other words, does there exist a pair of functions $F(n,k), G(n,k)$ obeying equation 
>      $$F(n+1,k)-F(n,k)=G(n,k+1)-G(n,k)\tag{$\ast$}$$
>      from which $(1)$ can be proved? That is, is it possible to transform  the defining series for $\zeta(4):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^4$ by means of the [Wilf-Zeilberger method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair) (or the [Markov-WZ Method](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/EJC/Volume_11/PDF/v11i1r53.pdf)) into the faster series $(1)$? (b) **Most likely there isn't any such a pair $(F, G)$, but I do not have the means to use these methods on my own.**

**Short description of section 1 of Alf van der Poorten's paper**

The defining series for $\zeta(3):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^3$ and $\zeta(2):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^2$ are accelerated resulting in

\begin{equation*}
\zeta (2)=3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }
\frac{1}{n^{2}\binom{2n}{n}},\tag{2}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\zeta (3)=\frac{5}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }
\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{3}\binom{2n}{n}}\tag{3}.
\end{equation*}

For instance, $(3)$ follows from the identity

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^{3}}-2\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\left( -1\right) ^{n-1}}{n^{3}\binom{2n}{n}}=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k^{3}\binom{N+k}{k}\binom{N}{k}}-\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k^{3}\binom{2k}{k}}\tag{4},
\end{equation*}

by letting $N\rightarrow \infty $ and noticing that

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k^{3}\binom{N+k}{k}\binom{N}{k}}=0.
\end{equation*}

Equality $(4)$ can be explained as follows:

1. Write
   \begin{equation*}
   X_{n,k}=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^{2}\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{n-1}{k}},\qquad D_{n,k}=\frac{(-1)^{k}}{n^{2}\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{n-1}{k}}\qquad k<n.
   \end{equation*}
2. Notice that $$X_{n,k}=D_{n,k-1}-D_{n,k}.\tag{5}$$ Hence
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{X_{n,k}}{n} &=&\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left( \frac{D_{n,k-1}}{
   n}-\frac{D_{n,k}}{n}\right) =\frac{D_{n,0}}{n}-\frac{D_{n,n-1}}{n} \\
   &=&\frac{1}{n^{3}}-2\frac{\left( -1\right) ^{n-1}}{n^{3}\binom{2n}{n}},\qquad\frac{D_{n,0}}{n} =\frac{1}{n^{3}},\quad \frac{D_{n,n-1}}{n}=2\frac{
   \left( -1\right) ^{n-1}}{n^{3}\binom{2n}{n}}
   \end{eqnarray*}
3. Sum over $k$, $1\leq
   k\leq n-1$
   \begin{equation*}
   \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}X_{n,k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left( D_{n,k-1}-D_{n,k}\right)
   =D_{n,0}-D_{n,n-1}.
   \end{equation*}
4. Now, summing over $n$, $1\leq n\leq N$, and noticing that
   \begin{equation*}
   \frac{X_{n,k}}{n}=E_{n,k}-E_{n-1,k},\qquad E_{n,k}=\frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k^{3}\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{n}{k}},\tag{6}
   \end{equation*}
   we obtain
   \begin{equation*}
   \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\sum_{n=k+1}^{N}\frac{X_{n,k}}{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}
   \sum_{n=k+1}^{N}\left( E_{n,k}-E_{n-1,k}\right) =\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(
   E_{N,k}-E_{k,k}\right). 
   \end{equation*}
5. So, on the one hand
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   \sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{X_{n,k}}{n} &=&\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{
   n^{3}}-2\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\left( -1\right) ^{n-1}}{n^{3}\binom{2n}{n}},\tag{7}
   \end{eqnarray*}
   and on the other hand
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   \sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{X_{n,k}}{n} 
   &=&\sum_{k=1}^{N}E_{N,k}-\sum_{k=1}^{N}E_{k,k} \\
   &=&\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k^{3}\binom{N+k}{k}\binom{N}{k}}
   -\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k^{3}\binom{2k}{k}}.\tag{8}
   \end{eqnarray*}
   The identity $(4)$ follows.

**Remarks**

1. The combination of equations $(5)$ and $(6)$ forms an identity of the form $(\ast)$, which is equation $(6.1.2)$ of [3, chapter 6] (Zeilberger's Algorithm).
2. As for $(2)$, [2, section 1] actually explains how to accelerate $\eta(2):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n-1}/n^{2}$ and obtain $(2)$, using the
   relation $\eta(s) = \left(1-2^{1-s}\right) \zeta(s)$. As such, if feasible, I expect that accelerating $\eta(4)$ might be easier than $\zeta(4)$.

**References**

1. [Henri Cohen, *Généralisation d'une Construction de R. Apéry*](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/BSMF/BSMF_1981__109_/BSMF_1981__109__269_0/BSMF_1981__109__269_0.pdf)
2. [Alfred van der Poorten, *Some wonderful formulae... Footnotes to Apery's proof of the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$*](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/SDPP/SDPP_1978-1979__20_2/SDPP_1978-1979__20_2_A6_0/SDPP_1978-1979__20_2_A6_0.pdf)
3. [Marko Petkovsek, Herbert Wilf, Doron Zeilberger, A = B](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.pdf)

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @Masacroso In short, can  (1)  be derived from an identity similar to (4)?

Comment: See also this fast converging series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function#Numerical_algorithms