# How to calculate this infinite serise

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$
\frac{2 \sqrt 2}{99^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(4n)!(1103+26390n)}{(4^n 99^n n!)^4}
$$

How to calculate? I can't think how to. Wolfram said

$$
\frac{1}{\pi} - \frac{2206\sqrt2}{99^2}
$$

Comment: Your expression is not very readable.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{2√2}{99^2} \sum_{n=1}^{∞} \frac{(4n)!(1103+26390n)}{(4^n 99^n n!)^4)}$ ?

Comment: @frederick99: complete with mismatch of parentheses

Comment: Please use `\sqrt` instead of the non-ASCII character `√`. It allows for better portability. It also formats better: $\sqrt2$ vs $√2$.

Comment: what does Wolfram Alpha say?

Comment: This smells of Ramanujan...

Comment: I have the strong feeling *Ramanujan* has something to do with it.

Comment: @Chappers: as a matter of fact... https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/pi/ramanujan.html

Comment: The derivation is heavily related with elliptic integrals.

Comment: see related http://math.stackexchange.com/a/434237/72031 and some theory in my blogs http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/03/modular-equations-and-approximations-to-pi-part-2.html

Answer (score 2):

This question is equivalent to showing that 
$$\frac1{\pi} = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{9801} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(4k)!(1103+26390k)}{(k!)^4 396^{4k}}\!.$$

This formula for $\frac{1}{\pi}$ was discovered by Ramanujan, and for a discussion of its derivation, I suggest the following: [Motivation for Ramanujan's mysterious $\pi$ formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14115/motivation-for-ramanujans-mysterious-pi-formula).

Since your sum is readily seen to be the same as Ramanujan's formula only differing in the factorization of numbers and in that your sum begins at $k = 1$ instead of $k = 0$. Thus, 
$$\frac{2 \sqrt 2}{99^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(4n)!(1103+26390n)}{(4^n 99^n n!)^4}$$ is $\frac{1}{\pi}$ minus the $k=0$ term of Ramanujan's series, namely,
$\frac{2 \cdot 1103 \sqrt 2}{99^2}.$