# Finding the value of pi using calculus.

Tags: calculus, limits, pi

I am new to calculus and not have much knowledge of how it works, I thought about finding the value of $\pi$ using the idea of dividing a circle into multiple parts and finding its area and thus extracting $\pi$ from it, the formula I got was 
$$\lim_{d \to 0} 4d\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor 1/d\rfloor} \sqrt{1-(nd)^2} $$

Is there any way to simplify this formula using calculus as the only way currently I can solve this is taking $d$ as small value and adding each part manually.

Thanks for answers in advance

Comment: You forgot a square root.

Comment: If you are trying to approximate the area of the unitary circle, I think you are looking for $$\lim_{d\to 0}4d\sum_{n=1}^{1/d} \sqrt{1-(nd)^2}$$ rather than the thing you wrote.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not computing $\pi$ by calculus, but by numerical computation. Because calculus will tell you (after involved computation) that this is... $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks, what you wrote is what i was trying to write but i did many  mistakes as i was trying to learn special signs on stackexchange

Comment: Methods of calculus can be used to prove many formulas for $\pi$ which can be effectively used for evaluating $\pi$ upto a desired level of accuracy. The simplest such approach is based on infinite series $$\arctan x=x-\frac{x^{3}}{3}+\frac{x^{5}}{5}-\dots$$ and the trigonometric identity $$\frac{\pi}{4}=4\arctan\frac{1}{5}-\arctan\frac{1}{239}$$ There are more esoteric infinite series for evaluating $\pi$, most notably the one given by Ramanujan (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14115/72031) but unfortunately they require a lot more of calculus than is typically studied in a first course.

Comment: Your approach is simpler but not very effective in getting value of $\pi$ to a good level of accuracy.

Comment: Read up on Taylor series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series and apply them to trig functions  https://www.google.com/search?q=calculating+pi+via+taylor+series&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: I am really thankful for such great answers, I am currently a high school student and i don't think i will be currently able to understand things like higher calculus and taylor series.

Comment: Besides noting this is the area of a circle, you could alternatively consider trig substitutions, but ofc, that's circular and results in the use of $\pi$, so...

Answer (score 1):

$\pi$ can be found using calculus as the arc length of a semicircle of radius $1$ (this method is similar to the one you suggest...). Since the circle has equation $x^2+y^2=1$, the [arc length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length) formula gives $$\pi=\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$$

Answer (score 0):

There are [many ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80) to approximate $\pi$, all reliant on limits if not calculus in some way or another. (Well, arguably all use calculus because they require a definition of $\pi$, which is either as an arc length from intrinsic calculus or an area from integral calculus.) You can write $\pi$ as various integrals and sums, but in practice we compute these integrals by cutting an area into $n$ strips (say), and so every method of approximating $\pi$ can be seen as defining a sequence $\{\pi_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\pi_n=\pi$.

The most important difference between these options is *how quickly* $\pi_n$ approaches $\pi$ as $n$ grows. If you cut a circle into $n$ sectors each subtending $2\pi/n$ radians and approximate the sectors as triangles, the first-order approximation $\sin\theta\approx\theta$ of the area gives a $O(1/n^3)$ error per sector, and $O(1/n^2)$ for $\pi$ itself. Unfortunately, $|\pi_n-\pi|\in O(n^{-p})$ isn't as impressive as it sounds at first, because each extra decimal place of precision requires multiplying $n$ by $10^{1/p}$. It's not so bad if you can increase $p$ ([which you can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanks_transformation#Example)), but it'd be much better if the error shrank exponentially, so an extra decimal place only requires *adding* a constant to $n$.

Amazingly, many techniques can do **even better than that**. Exponentially shrinking errors $\epsilon_n:=|\pi_n-\pi|$ satisfy $\epsilon_{n+1}\approx r\epsilon_n$ with $0<r<1$. But if $\epsilon_{n+1}\in O(\epsilon_{n+1}^p)$ with $p>1$, we have a form of *superlinear convergence* in which the number of correct decimal places multiplies approximately by $p$ every time you increase $n$. It's not important to make $p$ much bigger than $1$, and approaches achieving $p>2$ tend to be (i) so computationally complex at each iteration they're not necessarily "faster" overall and (ii) dependent on much more advanced theory. For your purposes, $p=2$ may be a sweet spot, e.g. if you use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein%27s_algorithm#Quadratic_convergence_(1984)) approach.

A further benefit of the above link is that it allows you to build on previous calculations; a sequence of the form $\pi_{n+1}=f(\pi_n)$, or at least one of the form $\pi_n=g(a_n^{(1)},\,\cdots,\,a_n^{(k)}),\,a_{n+1}^{(i)}=f_i(a_n^{(i)})$, allows you to continue if you want more precision, whereas if you didn't chop up a circle you have to start over again with more slices. *Or do you?* Your original approach can be fruitful if you keep doubling the number of slices. [A calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Middle_Ages) with a $3\times 2^{28}$-gon obtained the equivalent of $17$ decimal places in 1424.